# How to remove the empty space beneath my custom badge component?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Why is there a space beneath the following badge component? I did not use any padding or margins. I assume this maybe is a line-height issue, but how can I get rid of this space? I want the height of the badge to exactly fit its content.

[image]

```html
<div class="flex w-full">
  <div>
    <span class="badge inline-block leading-3 overflow-hidden rounded select-none cursor-pointer white py-0.5 px-1.5 text-xs mr-0.5" style="background-color: rgb(13, 155, 131);">
      Feature
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Playtailwind link:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/arRAQd01di

**Update:**

Removing the inner div seems to resolve the issue, but I do not understand why?

Comment: could you paste the actual markup? instead of a screenshot? or better yet put it in a playtailwind link.

Comment: @RicardoSilva Added the playtailwind link.

Comment: if you remove the inline block it solves the issue. Is that something you can remove without losing the behavior you want?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I posted an image, an example and a playground link, should be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `<div>` has `display: block` so the height is based on the default line-height it inherits of 24px.

When you remove the inner `<div>` the outer `<div>` has a `display: flex` so `line-height` has no affect on it. So it picks up the height of the inner `<span>` which has a height of 12px.